# Python WIN 10: Run WMIC in shell with ADMINISTRATOR priviledges

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the following in a shell. It doesn't work though. The WMIC command has to be run as an administrator. How to I use subprocess.run as an Administrator?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('wmic product where name="Application I Wish To Uninstall" call uninstall', shell=True)
```

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` calls `CreateProcess`, which creates a new process using a duplicate of the caller's access token. Thus one option is to run your Python script from an already elevated PowerShell or cmd shell.

Comment: Trusted system services are allowed to elevate, such as the Task Scheduler and the Application Information (Appinfo) service. The latter is used via the "runas" operation of `ShellExecute[Ex]`. You can find existing answers on SO that implement this approach in order to respawn a script with admin access.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

- start your command prompt as administrator
- run your python script like "python mypythonapp.py"